# private + final = "Нельзя изменить"

Tags: java

В некоторых источниках, в литературе пишут именно такое высказывание. 
У меня такой вопрос: "Является ли это утверждение абсолютным?" Или это сделано специально для общего понимания?

Я здесь на форуме прочитала, что существует рефлексия и всё таки можно повлиять на это. Может существуют другие возможности?

Comment: У каждого модификатора своя роль: `final` - говорит о том, что значение поля можно установить только однажды. Если вы попробуете его изменить, то компилятор не даст вам этого сделать. `private` - отвечает лишь за видимость поля. И в связи с этим, мне кажется, что выражение "private + final = Нельзя изменить” не является корректным. Модификатор `final` - сам по себе говорит о том, что поле является константой.

Comment: а можно private метод изменить в процессе?

Comment: Изменить private метод в процессе? В каком процессе? Что вы имеете в виду? Как я уже говорил, модификатор private определяет видимость поля/метода.

Comment: спасибо Arsenicum я поняла, как можно повлиять на видимость private   в некоторых случаях

Comment: Пожалуйста, но советую вам крайне осторожно применять эти методы на практике, скорее в учебных целях.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Все зависит от того, для чего использовать данные модификаторы:

1. Если модификатор `final` используется для **поля** класса, тогда
   поле необходимо определить в конструкторе класса (причем единожды за
   весь конструктор), либо, непосредственно, в месте объявления.
   Совокупность модификаторов `private final` для **поля** накладывает запрет на изменение (определить данное поле возможно либо в конструкторе, либо в месте объявления за счет `final`) и видимость данного поля ограничивается методами данного класса (за счет `private`).
2. Если модификатор `final` используется для **метода** класса, то он запрещает переопределение данного метода в классах-наследниках.
   Использование же пары модификаторов `private final` для метода класса лишено смысла, так как `private` ограничит доступ к данному методу пределами класса, а `final` запретит его переопределение в наследниках. т.е. потомки этот метод не увидят, а, следовательно, не смогут переопределить.

При использовании рефлексии значение поля с модификатором `private` можно изменить, но при этом для `final` поля такое недопустимо (никакого исключения/предупреждения сгенерировано не будет, но поле не изменится).

*Контрольный пример:*

```
class WithPrivateFinalField { 
    private int i = 1; 
    private final String s = "String S"; 
    private String s2 = "String S2"; 

    public String toString() { 
        return "i = " + i + ", " + s + ", " + s2; 
    } 
} 

public class ModifyngPrivateFields {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WithPrivateFinalField pf = new WithPrivateFinalField(); 

        Field f = pf.getClass().getDeclaredField("i"); 
        f.setAccessible(true); 
        f.setInt(pf, 47); 
        System.out.println(pf);  // i = 47, String S, String S2

        f = pf.getClass().getDeclaredField("s"); 
        f.setAccessible(true); 
        f.set(pf, "MODIFY S"); 
        System.out.println(pf);  // i = 47, String S, String S2


        f = pf.getClass().getDeclaredField("s2"); 
        f.setAccessible(true); 
        f.set(pf, "MODIFY S2"); 
        System.out.println(pf);  // i = 47, String S, MODIFY S2
    } 
}
```

Comment: да спасибо за ответ, с этим я разобралась. Можно например сделать отложенную инициализацию, я так понимаю для переменных, разными путями. ну и с методами тоже ясно, их нельзя унаследовать и изменять, но можно использовать это все логично. Но оказывается что не всегда, поэтому и задаю вопрос)

Comment: Под отложенной инициализацией вы понимаете, что инициализировать поле класса при первом обращении? Тогда модификатор final не нужен. Даже IDE будет ругаться, если помеченное final поле попытаться присвоить где-то, кроме места объявления и инициализации

Comment: Мне кажется, что человек просто не успел увидеть ваш пример кода после доработки ответа.

Comment: Да я не успела прочитать, сейчас вижу и понимаю), но вот если записать так к примеру: public class Main extends Activity { 
final int a; public Main(int a) { this.a = a; } мы же сможем повлиять, на значение в процессе? те если public+final исходя из ответа можно смело считать абсолютным высказыванием? и никак не подобраться и не обойти это?

Comment: @Dasha, мы задаём финальное поле `a` однажды в конструкторе. Далее его будет нельзя изменить. public+final - говорит о том, что поле будет видно для других, но изменять его всё равно будет нельзя.

Comment: Да, но я же могу перед тем как создать final a, в конструкторе сделать всё что угодно и повлиять на значение a, но только потом оно станет константным так? А значит, что при след. запуске эта a может быть другой? правильно?

Comment: Немного не так. В этом примере поменять `s` нельзя, т.к. компилятор считает его константным выражением и встраивает везде, где может.  Если инициализировать `s` в конструкторе, или заменить на `new String("String S")`, то все заменится ([см. enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516381/)). Док на `set` вообще утверждает, что его применение к `final` полям после публикации объекта допускает неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @zRrr Кажется, _Java_ своим стандартом не допускает неопределенного поведения (`undefined behaviour`) в отличие от _C++_, или я где-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Dasha, в конструкторе вы можете лишь единожды задать значение для поля `a` и всё. Вы задали константе значения - она такой и будет. Что вы имели ввиду под "след. запуске"?

Comment: @Arsenicum Мне кажется, что человек подумал на счет `static final` поля, которое можно определить лишь в месте объявления, но человек думает, что можно и в конструкторе, если я правильно понял.

Comment: zRrr дал очень интересный пример я не разобралась ещё((( 
 Arsenicum, мне же никто не запретит сделать проверку в конструкторе например если первый запуск то a = 1, а если нет то a = 2? И значение "а" при каждом запуске activity, будет иметь разное значение так?

Comment: @Dasha Вы понимаете, что каждый экземпляр класса имеет собственные поля (кроме `static` полей), которые не имеют ничего общего (кроме типов) с полями других экземпляров данного класса (+ в конструкторе вы лишь 1 раз можете присвоить значение `final` полю, т.е. в одном и том же конструкторе не выйдет в начале выставить одно значение, а в его конце другое). Когда же вы создадите новый экземпляр данного класса (посредством `new` иначе же вы будете ссылаться на другой экземпляр и конструктор не будет вызван), то он приобретет свое собственное поле `final`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive в оригинале "Use in any other context may have unpredictable effects" - непредсказуемые эффекты. Я не представляю себе внутренности jvm, поэтому не могу придумать, как эту непредсказуемость получить, кроме классического прикола с не-volatile флагом на выход из цикла в другом потоке, который и без final прекрасно обходится.

Comment: StateItPrimitive да, я понимаю, что вы написали, но я немного другое спрашивала. А как же смотрите здесь, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1196207 Всё я запуталась, думала, что просто как-то можно изменить и нельзя категорически писать так в литературе(

Comment: @Dasha, в ссылке говорится о доступе к полю с модификатором `private`, а мы говорим о изменении `final`, которое невозможно.

Comment: @Dasha Но в примере на en SO меняют доступность `private`, но не `final` поля. Я так понимаю, что за такие вещи отвечает JVM, которая не позволит такому произойти (как например, можно сделать на с _const_'ами в _C++_, получив в итоге _undefined behaviour_).

Comment: ясно, спасибо ребят, что дали информацию, очень полезно. комментарии помогли больше чем ответ)) спасибо ещё раз всем.

Comment: @Dasha Если ответ _Andrew Bystrov_ дал вам исчерпывающую информацию, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его "галочкой" рядом со "стрелочками", чтобы он не висел в списке не отвеченных.

Comment: Да мне подсказали) спасибо

Comment: есть маленькая хитрость с `final`. Переменную можно менять, если объявить ее как массив с одним элементом: `final int[] myVar = new int[0]` и в дальнейшем обращаться к ней как `myVar[0]`. Может быть пригодится

Comment: `final int[] myVar = new int[1]`*

Answer (score 3):

#### private + final != “Нельзя изменить”

Небольшое дополнение к соседнему ответу: изменить значение `final` поля всё-таки можно. Нужно всего лишь с использованием той же рефлексии снять этот модификатор с поля. Можно написать для этого отдельный метод, например, такой:

```
private static void setAbsolutelyAccessible(Field field) {
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // ignored exceptions
    }
}
```

В классе `Field` имеется приватное поле `modifiers`, в котором в виде битовой маски хранится список модификаторов поля. Выражением `field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL` просто "снимаем" модификатор `final` с поля.

Пример:

> Предположим есть класс `A`:
>
> ```
> public static class A {
>     private final Integer i = 100;
>
>     @Override
>     public String toString() {
>         return i.toString();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Далее используем наш метод и переопределяем значение:
>
> ```
> A a = new A();
> System.out.println(a);    // 100
>
> Field field = A.class.getDeclaredField("i");
> setAbsolutelyAccessible(field);
>
> field.set(a, 10_000);
> System.out.println(a);    // 10000
> ```

#### Ограничения

Однако, имеется следующее ограничение: поля примитивных типов или строковые литералы (простая строка в кавычках), инициализированные значением в месте определения, а не в конструкторе, скорее всего (зависит от вендора и настроек компилятора), будут заинлайнены в местах использования и изменить их уже точно не удастся. Например:

```
public static class B {
    private final String s = "hello";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

При попытке поменять значение такого поля ничего не произойдёт:

```
B b = new B();
System.out.println(b);    // "hello"

Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("s");
setAbsolutelyAccessible(field);

field.set(b, "world");
System.out.println(b);    // "hello"
```

Однако, если поле иницилазировано в конструкторе, (или не примитивом и не литералом, даже, например, через `new String("hello")`) - всё уже можно изменить:

```
public static class B {
    private final String s;

    public B() {
        this.s = "hello";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

И результат:

```
B b = new B();
System.out.println(b);    // "hello"

Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("s");
setAbsolutelyAccessible(field);

field.set(b, "world");
System.out.println(b);    // "world"
```