# Как обойти final в java?

Tags: java, android

Надо проверить массив на длину. И если он пустой создать маркеры, а если нет - обновлять их местоположение. Но никак не могу достучаться до массива маркеров. Сволоч объявлен `final`.

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Marker[] marker = new Marker[fullDrivers.size()];
        final Marker[] finalMarker = marker;

        MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (fullDrivers.size()>=1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fullDrivers.size(); i++) {
                        if (finalMarker[i]!=null){
                            finalMarker[i].setPosition(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng()));
                        }
                        finalMarker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
},0,6000);
```

Я вынужден его так делать. Как мне обойти это?

Comment: Зачем его обходить? Ну, можете в классе создать поле и обращаться к нему. Без this, просто обращаться.

Comment: @Rou1997 не понел можете по четче показать ?

Comment: Убрать final ?)

Comment: пытался тогда  finalMarker[i].setPosition(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())); ругается что обьявего финал

Comment: Укажите полное сообщение об ошибке и строку, на которой она возникает.

Comment: Использовать массив в "обёртке" ака `ArrayList` - его размер меняется без пересоздания и `final` этому не помеха.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модификатор `final` не делает переменную константой, он всего лишь делает константой ссылку на переменную. В случае с примитивами, если ссылка становится константой, то и переменная тоже (не Ваш случай), в случаях с объектами это значит, что переменную нельзя поменять на другую, но параметры текущей можно изменять.

Проблема не в модификаторe `final`, а в непонимании его сути, но так как Вы не расписали, что значит `достучаться`, сложно предположить в чем настоящая проблема - ругается компилятор или ошибка в процессе выполнения? Вы везде опираетесь на `fullDrivers.size()`, особенно в цикле, хотя правильнее было бы опираться на `finalMarker.length`, вдруг за промежуток времени до выполнения в главном потоке у Вас изменился размер `fullDrivers.size()` и Вы лезете за пределы массива? `runOnUiThread` не гарантирует моментальное выполнения в главном потоке, он всего лишь ставит Ваш блок кода в очередь на выполнение в главном потоке.

Могу предложить вариант написания кода без модификатора `final` у массива маркеров:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Marker[] marker = new Marker[fullDrivers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
            if (marker[i] != null) {
                marker[i].setPosition(
                        transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())
                );
            }
            marker[i] = mMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                           .position(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng()))
            );
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 6000);
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

А когда надо остановите повтор выполнения методом:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы каждый раз пересоздаете массив. Ветка `if(finalMarker[i]!=null)` никогда не выполнится.
2. Каждые 6 секунд все маркеры буду двоиться, а потом троиться и так далее.... При всем при этом массив смысла не имеет, код эквивалентен созданию маркеров раз в 6 секунд. Вероятно else пропустили.

Такой вариант:

```
private Map<Driver, Marker> markers = new HashMap<>();
private Timer timer = new Timer();

void initTimer(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        void run(){
            runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                void run(){
                    updateMarkers();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 6000);
}

void updateMarkers(){
   for(Driver driver: fullDrivers){
       Marker marker = markers.get(driver);
       if(marker == null){ 
           // добавляем новый маркер
           markers.add(driver, mMap.addMarker(
               new MarkerOptions()
                   .position(transfomation(driver.getLatlng())));
       } else {
           // изменяем существующий
           marker.setPosition(transfomation(driver.getLatlng()));
       }
   }
   //Удаляем лишние маркеры
   if(markers.size() > fullDrivers.size()){
       Iterator<Map.Entry<Driver, Marker>> it = markers.entrySet().iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()){
           Map.Entry<Driver, Marker> entry = it.next();
           if(!fullDrivers.contains(entry.getKey())){
               // Удаляем маркер. Что-то типа
               mMap.removeMarker(entry.getValue());
               it.remove();
           }
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Щас попробую вашим методом

Comment: откуда появился Driver ???

Comment: Из `List<Driver> fullDrivers`. Возможно у вас там какое-то другое название класса, вы не указали в вопросе что там лежит.

Comment: да .List<FullDriver> fullders = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Пытался сделать так

Comment: внизу поделился ошибкой посмотри пожалуйста

Comment: Добавление прошло успешно !Ща попытаюсь удалить !

Comment: // Удаляем маркер. Что-то типа
               mMap.removeMarker(entry.getValue());

Comment: у mMap нет метода removeMarker

Comment: @elik этот код - пример. Какие методы и классы вы используете мне неизвестно. Комментарий как бы на это намекал - "что-то типа"...

Comment: ПОнел вмне просто указали правльный путь да ?спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете изменить переменную с модификатором final, это обозначения констант а тут `finalMarker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())));` вы ей присваиваете новое значения, уберите финал или у вас есть другой массив маркеров.
Ну а если уж очень нужно, то вроде рефлекшен может менять все что угодно, то вот сылка:
[private + final = "Нельзя изменить"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498742/private-final-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateMarkers() {
    for(FullDriver driver: fullDrivers){
        Marker marker = markers.get(driver);
        if(marker == null){
            // добавляем новый маркер
            markers.put((List<FullDriver>) driver, mMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(transfomation(driver.getLatlng()))));
        } else {
            // изменяем существующий
            marker.setPosition(transfomation(driver.getLatlng()));
        }
    }
}
```

вот и ошибка

```
05-12 15:43:16.341 3324-3324/xyz.justart.getallandposition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: xyz.justart.getallandposition, PID: 3324
                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: xyz.justart.getallandposition.FullDriver cannot be cast to java.util.List
                                                                                 at xyz.justart.getallandposition.MapsActivity.updateMarkers(MapsActivity.java:207)
                                                                                 at xyz.justart.getallandposition.MapsActivity.access$100(MapsActivity.java:32)
                                                                                 at xyz.justart.getallandposition.MapsActivity$2$1.run(MapsActivity.java:194)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: 1. Вопросы в вопросы. 2. Сообщение об ошибке прочитай.

Comment: ошибка говорит что Фулл дравер не может быть привден к списку

Comment: Ну и как эта ошибка связана с final, если у тебя там тип не тот?

Comment: @Qwertiy  да я не прав.как исправить ? я делаю

Comment: for( List<FullDriver> driver: fullDrivers) компилятор подчеркивет его красным

Comment: (List<FullDriver>) уберите

Comment: Сделал)Только добавние уже полнел как делать получилось )Щас пробую удаление !СПасибо Юрий !как получится удаление то  скажу !