# Почему маркеры не обновляются?

Tags: java, android

Есть поток в котором происходит добавние маркеров и послдеющее их обновление

```
timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {



                MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                                /*    if (var!=null) {
                                        if (fullDrivers.size() >= 1) {
                                          for (int i = 0; i < fullDrivers.size(); i++) {
                                            finalMarker[i].setPosition(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng()));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < fullDrivers.size(); i++) {
                                            finalMarker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())));
                                            var="+++";
                                        }
                                    }*/
                        if (icount!=0){
                            for (int i = 0; i < fullDrivers.size(); i++){
                            finalMarker[i].setPosition(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng()));
                            Log.d(TAG,"Obnovlenie prowlo Udacno!");
                        }
                        }else{
                            for (int i = 0; i < fullDrivers.size(); i++) {
                            finalMarker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transfomation(fullDrivers.get(i).getLatlng())));
                                icount++;
                                Log.d(TAG,"Pervoe  Dobavlenie markerov prowlo Udacno !");
                        }


                        }

                        //-------------------------------------
                    }
                });
               /*
                }*/
            }
        },0,6000);
```

C добавением проблем нету.А вот при обновлении вылетает  с ошибкой

```
> 05-12 00:33:30.541 9613-9613/xyz.justart.getallandposition
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: xyz.justart.getallandposition, PID: 9613
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)'
> on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
> xyz.justart.getallandposition.MapsActivity$2$1.run(MapsActivity.java:133)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: `finalMarker[i] == null`.

Comment: @post_zeew непонел .Не моглиб в показать где ошибка???я уже по вкому пробую не получается .

Comment: неужели java.lang.NullPointerException ни о чем не говорит? https://habrahabr.ru/post/221243/

Answer (score 2):

Если смотреть на код из Вашего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664786/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-final-%D0%B2-java), то предположу, что Вы проинициализировали массив с маркерами с заданным размером, но не заполнили его маркерами. Получается, что все элементы массива у Вас `null`, Ваш блок кода с `if (icount!=0)` не успевает попадать в то русло, где они инициализируются, но попадает в то русло, когда у них вызываются методы, а когда Вы пытаетесь вызывать методы у `null`, Вы непременно получаете `NullPointerException`.